# Streaming in ffmpeg using RTP

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming

## Scenario

I'm trying to stream a video between 2 hosts using RTP. I have previously solved this problem using VLC using the following 2 commands

### Server Side

`cvlc video_file.mp4 --sout "#transcode{vcodec=h264, acodec=mpga, ab=128, channels=2, samplerate=44100}: duplicate{dst=rtp{dst=10.X.X.X, port=5004, mux=ts}}" --run-time 40 vlc://quit`

### Client Side

`cvlc rtp://@:5004 --sout "#transcode{vcodec=h264, acodec=mpga, ab=128, channels=2, samplerate=44100}: std{access=file, mux=mp4, dst=downloaded.mp4}" --run-time 40 vlc://quit`

## Requirement

Now I want to achieve the same but with FFMPEG. *What would be the equivalent command?*

## Work done till now

### Server Side

`ffmpeg -re -i video_file.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -an -f rtp rtp://10.X.X.X:5004 -vn -acodec libtwolame -f rtp rtp://10.X.X.X:5005`

### Client Side

`ffmpeg -i rtp://10.X.X.X:5004 -vcodec libx264 -an -i rtp://10.5.19.244:5005 -acodec libtwolame -vn -t 00:00:35 downloaded.mp4`

However, I cannot record the received stream this way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assume that the IP of the client is 10.0.0.2

### Code to run on server side

`ffmpeg -re -thread_queue_size 4 -i source_video_file.mp4 -strict 2 -vcodec copy -an -f rtp rtp://10.0.0.2:6005 -acodec copy -vn -sdp_file saved_sdp_file -f rtp rtp://10.0.0.2:7005`

After running this code, an SDP file should be generated named `saved_sdp_file`. This should be transferred to the client, which needs it to receive the stream

### Code to run on client side

`ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist "file,rtp,udp" -i saved_sdp_file -strict 2 saved_video_file.mp4`

Comment: The client side gives me an error: `Unrecognized option '2'.`

Comment: This doesn't work. On the server: `Output file does not contain any stream`. On the client (after removing audio stream from above): `Could not find codec parameters for stream 0, unspecified size`

Answer (score 1):

**Considering server address to be 10.158.210.39 and streaming on UDP port 5155**

Server side:

```
ffmpeg -re -i test_video.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f rtp_mpegts -sdp_file test_video.sdp "rtp://10.158.210.39:5155"
```

*rtp_mpegts* is a format that is supported by VLC also.
There is no need to copy the *sdp* file to client to receive the stream.

Client side:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist rtp,udp -i "rtp://10.158.210.39:5155" save.mp4
```

The received stream is saved to *save.mp4*

To receive using ffplay:

```
ffplay -protocol_whitelist rtp,udp -i "rtp://10.158.210.39:5155"
```

This will play the video (even in SSH connection if you are using mobaxterm)